# jquery if statement radio buttons processes every time

Tags: jquery, if-statement, radio-button

I have a pair of radio buttons as follows

```
  <label class="radio inline" for="radios-0">
     <input type="radio" name="newsletter" id="radios-0" value="1" checked="checked">
        Yes
  </label>
  <label class="radio inline" for="radios-1">
     <input type="radio" name="newsletter" id="radios-1" value="0">
        No
  </label>
```

The form they are a part of Post via ajax and the script works fine. I have an additional part to check if they selected yes or no on the radio buttons and if yes subscribe to the mailing list. However no matter if yes or no are selected it still enters into the list.

Is it due to them being the same name? however without being the same name both can be checked.

```
if ($('input:radio[name="newsletter"]').is(':checked') && $('input:radio[name="newsletter"]').val == 1) {
    //add email to newsletter list
}
```

Comment: Thank you this has solved it, shame you commented instead of answer as I cant select it as answer now.

Comment: @PhilNewell If you switch to `input#radios-0` then remove the 2nd condition.  The first is sufficient and the 2nd is all wrong anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector will return both radio buttons and is will check if any of them is checked

> is() Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element,
>   or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements
>   matches the given arguments, [reference](http://api.jquery.com/is/).

You have `id` in both radio button you better use `id` selector here.

```
if($('#radios-0:checked').length)
{

}
```

Comment: That will always be true as `$` always returns an object.  Also you're missing a `)`.

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is what you need!

```
if($('input:radio[name="newsletter"]:checked').val() == 1){
    //add email to newsletter list
}
```

hope this helps

also why are your radio buttons inside the label elements?

```
<label class="radio inline" for="radios-0">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="newsletter" id="radios-0" value="1" checked="checked">
<label class="radio inline" for="radios-1">No</label>
<input type="radio" name="newsletter" id="radios-1" value="0">
```

maybe this would be better?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your part of the code:

```
$('input:radio[name="newsletter"]').val == 1
```

with this

```
parseInt($('input:radio[name="newsletter"]').val(), 10) == 1
```

and try again

or

```
$('input:radio[name="newsletter"]').val() == "1"
```

Comment: May as well just check for the string `"1"` and skip the `parseInt`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
var radioVal = $("input[name='newsletter']:checked").val();
    if (radioVal == 1) {
        alert("Yes");
    }else{
        alert("NO");
    }
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wLDaA/)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('input:radio[name="newsletter"]:checked').val() == 1 ) {
        //add email to newsletter list
    }
```

Because You check if the radio is checked and it is.
You have to check which is selected.